# Compare files with awk

Tags: awk, compare, comparison

I have two similar files (both with 3 columns). I'd like to check if these two files contains the same elements (but listed in a different orders). First of all I'd like to compare only the 1st columns

file1.txt

```
"aba" 0 0 
"abc" 0 1
"abd" 1 1 
"xxx" 0 0
```

file2.txt

```
"xyz" 0 0
"aba" 0 0
"xxx" 0 0
"abc" 1 1
```

How can I do it using awk? I tried to have a look around but I've found only complicate examples. What if I want to include also the other two columns on the comparison? The output should give me the number of matching elements.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/i-have-two-files-file-1-contains-3.html

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To print the common *elements* in both files:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a{print $1}' file1 file2
"aba"
"abc"
"xxx"
```

Explanation:

`NR` and `FNR` are `awk` variables that store the total number of records and the number of records in the current files respectively (the default record is a line).

```
NR==FNR # Only true when in the first file 
{
    a[$1] # Build associative array on the first column of the file
    next  # Skip all proceeding blocks and process next line
}
($1 in a) # Check in the value in column one of the second files is in the array
{
    # If so print it
    print $1
}
```

If you want to match the whole lines then use `$0`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}$0 in a{print $0}' file1 file2
"aba" 0 0
"xxx" 0 0
```

Or a specific set of columns:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1,$2,$3];next}($1,$2,$3) in a{print $1,$2,$3}' file1 file2
"aba" 0 0
"xxx" 0 0
```

Comment: @iiSeymour     how to print 2nd cloumn of file1 if 1st cloumn of file2 found in associative array ?

Answer (score 6):

To print the number of matching elements, here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } $1 in a { c++ } END { print c }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results using your input:

```
3
```

---

If you'd like to add extra columns (for example, columns one, two and three), use a [pseudo-multidimensional array](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html#Multi_002ddimensional):

```
awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1,$2,$3]; next } ($1,$2,$3) in a { c++ } END { print c }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

Results using your input:

```
2
```

Comment: +1. Since OP's files only have 3 columns, it may be better to just use `a[$0]` instead of `a[$1,$2,$3]`. But then any unmatched invisible trailing spaces in either file can cause unexpected output. Maybe use rtrim or gsub for that.

Comment: Used it like this  -> za$ awk 'FNR==NR { a[$1]; next } !($1 in a)  END { print $1 }' test.csv test2.csv to print the unmatching records.

Comment: @zee: Thanks for the vote, but you don't need your `END` block