# Matching values from columns from two files, need to speed things up dramatically

Tags: awk

Here's the script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    LC_ALL=C
    while read line
    do
    gi=$(echo $line | awk '{print $2}')
    kegg=$(echo $line | awk '{print $1}')
    hitline=$(fgrep "$gi" blastoutput.tsv)
    if [ -n "$hitline" ]
    then
    echo "$hitline\t$kegg"
    fi
    done <genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod
```

genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod has 11,461,266 lines and looks like:

```
    hsa:1   21071030
    hsa:10  116295260
    hsa:100 47078295
    ...
```

I'm feeding the script a modified tabular blast output which looks like:

```
    consensus0_0_1_1142_+   gi  374264077   ref ZP_09622622.1       87.86   379 46  0   1   379 26  404 0.0  721
    consensus0_0_1_1142_+   gi  388456578   ref ZP_10138873.1       86.28   379 52  0   1   379 26  404 0.0  704
    consensus0_0_1_1142_+   gi  148358975   ref YP_001250182.1      87.34   379 48  0   1   379 26  404 0.0  703
    ...
```

The script works. However, it's incredibly slow and it's not going to get the job done as such.

Now, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065818/compare-files-with-awk) incredibly helpful.

I came as far as:

```
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}$3 in a{print $0}' genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod blastoutput.tsv
```

And it works and is very fast. My remaining problem is that I can't figure out how to make awk print the first column of the first file to the end of the lines of the second file that match from their third column with the array. I'm sorry I had to make a new thread about this. I don't have good enough reputation to "comment" this in the linked thread, nor do I have the reputation to ask this in the chats. Thanks.

So again: I want to print the lines from the blastoutput.tsv file that have a matching gi in the genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod file. Additionally, I want to print the first column of the genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod at the end of the matching blastoutput.tsv lines.

Comment: Is the 2nd column of the genes file supposed to correspond with the 3rd column of the blast file? It would be helpful to give us a short example of input with your desired output.

Comment: Yes, the values in the second column of the genes file correspond to the values in the third column of the blast file. However, both files have lots of values that are unique to them. I'm only interested in the values that are in both tables. I want the output to be just like blast output except with extra column in the end or beginning which has "hsa:1" or whatever value happened to be in the first column of the genes file.

Comment: This looks like a job for `join`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unforfunately, join's output specifiers are very rudimentary, so you have to specify every field.

```
join -1 2 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7,2.8,2.9,2.10,2.11,2.12,2.13,2.14,2.15,1.1 <(sort -bk2,2 genes_ncbi-gi.list.mod) <(sort -bk3,3 blastoutput.tsv)
```

I assume your shell is bash/ksh/zsh

Comment: This one seems to work. The number of lines in the output is the exact same as in the output of the awk line. Thanks a million!