# Compare file with different number format

Tags: sorting, awk, numbers, format

First of all I'd like to thank your community, you have been helping me tremendously over the past couple of months, thanks to your detailed answers and your comments.

However I came accross a snag. I want to compare 2 files containing simulation data. These files are the result of a previous operation which consists in extracting the desired data from 2 of output files.

So output-file1-> sorteddata1
   Output-file2-> sorteddata2

Sorteddata1 looks like that

```
0.200000e-4 a b c d e  
0.400000e-4 f g h i j  
0.560000e-4 k l m n o
            . 
            . 
            .
```

Sorteddata2

```
2.000000E-5 A 
3.600000E-5 B 
5.600000E-5 C 
      . 
      . 
      .
```

And what I would like this, sorteddata3:

```
0.200000e-4 a b c d e A
0.400000e-4 f g h i j
0.560000e-4 k l m n o C
            .
            .
            .
```

So if the number in the first column is the same, add the corresponding value from sorteddata2 in the 7th column of sorteddata1.

I wanted to start from here:

[Compare files with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065818/compare-files-with-awk)

But the number format from the first column of each file is different, so I don't get any return. I really want to use awk for this (personal preference, I kind of like it)

The goal is to plot this using gnuplot, so hopefully a blank in the last column won't be a problem.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`sprintf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to make the number stick to the same format:

> **sprintf**(format, expression1, ...)
>
> Return (without printing) the string that printf would have printed
>   out with the same arguments (see Printf).

Then, the logic is the same as in the linked answer, adding an `if/ default` case to print either the current line or it together with the matched line from the other file.

```
awk 'NR==FNR {value=sprintf("%e", $1)
              a[value]=$2
              next
             }
     {value2=sprintf("%e", $1)
      print $0, a[value2]
     }' f2 f1
```

For your given input, it returns:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{value=sprintf("%e", $1); a[value]=$2; next} {value2=sprintf("%e", $1); if (value2 in a) {print $0, a[value2] }' f2 f1
0.200000e-4 a b c d e A
0.400000e-4 f g h i j
0.560000e-4 k l m n o C
```

Note in comments you say that `E` format shows a "unterminated string" error to you. Hence, you can replace the `E` with `e` in the number format with `sub("E","e",$1)`. All together:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{value=sprintf("%e", $1); a[value]=$2; next} {sub("E","e",$1); value2=sprintf("%e", $1); print $0, a[value2] }' f2 f1
```

Comment: Hmmm I came accross a "unterminated string". It looks like it does not like the capital E. I don't have this error for the other "%e".

Comment: You can replace `E` with `e`. Give a try to this: `awk 'NR==FNR{value=sprintf("%e", $1); a[value]=$2; next} {sub("E","e",$1); value2=sprintf("%e", $1); print $0, a[value2] }' f2 f1`

Comment: Very well done sir.! Thank you very much, have a nice day !! :-)