# Multiple replacement awk script

Tags: awk

I would like to add an asterisk to keys in file1 if this string in found in file2.

Thanks, Bernardo

```
#file1
HPNK_00080  HPNK_00080  HPNK_04889  HAPS_1149   HAPS_1027   HAPS_0842   HPNK_04769  HAPS_1077   HPNK_10396  HPNK_04984  HPSD74_1027
HPNK_00090  HPNK_00090  HS308_01445 HAPS_0623   HAPS_0558   HS321_01221
HPNK_00277  HS312_01685 HS308_01448 HS306_01459 HPNK_00277  HS313_01643 HS310_01701 HS317_01870

#file2
HPNK_00080
HPNK_00090
HPNK_00210

#desired output
HPNK_00080* HPNK_00080  HPNK_04889  HAPS_1149   HAPS_1027   HAPS_0842   HPNK_04769  HAPS_1077   HPNK_10396  HPNK_04984  HPSD74_1027
HPNK_00090* HPNK_00090  HS308_01445 HAPS_0623   HAPS_0558   HS321_01221
HPNK_00277  HS312_01685 HS308_01448 HS306_01459 HPNK_00277  HS313_01643 HS310_01701 HS317_01870
```

I tried:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR { map[$1] = $2; next }
{
    for (key in map)
        if ($0 = key)
            $0 = $0"*"
    print
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare files with AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065818/compare-files-with-awk)

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is close to what you have.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{key[$1]++;next}
     NR!=FNR{if ($1 in key) $1 = $1 "*"; print}' file2 file1
```

The main differences are that it doesn't reference the non-existent `$2` in reading `file2`, and it uses a direct lookup of `$1` instead of a loop and `$0`, to see if the key is present while reading `file1`.

Comment: You don't need the `NR!=FNR`

Comment: @Jidder: No, I don't need the `NR!=FNR`, but I prefer it for symmetry.  I could do without the `next`given that `NR!=FNR` is there, too. I still prefer the clarity and symmetry.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Okay, it was just in case you didn't realise :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys in file1 are unique you could also do

```
awk '{$1 in key&&$1=$1"*";key[$1]}ARGIND==2' file2 file1
```