# How to check for occurrences of indexes in a file onto another by column and print out the result

Tags: python, linux, shell, csv, awk

So i have a file1.dat with indexes i need to check (one by line) and a file2.csv file where i wanna count the occurrences of each of those indexes by column and then print out the result for each index. Exemple:

file1.dat:

```
74568
75842
76822
77458
```

file2.csv:

```
"1470009615","62353","1","y","52669","74568","php"
"1470009617","31173","1","y","54725","31173","php"
"1470009617","16293","1","n","58892","75842","php"
"1470009636","50795","1","y","47004","50795","php"
```

So what i want, in this case, is to count how many times each of the indexes in file1.dat appear in column 6 and generate an output (file3.dat) like this:

```
74568    1
75842    1
76822    0
77458    0
```

I know the code to count by column with awk is something like this:

```
awk -F, '$6==(index)'
```

But how can i make it take the index from the list and print out the result properly?
Python scripts would help too.

Comment: This is why they invented RDBMS.

Comment: To get help with this one, you'll need to start writing some code yourself - on SO we can help resolve errors, but not tell you how to code something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compare files with AWK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15065818/compare-files-with-awk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{gsub(/"/,"",$6);A[$6]++;next}{print $1,A[$1]+0}' file2.csv file1.dat
```

**Input**

```
$ cat file1.dat
74568
75842
76822
77458

$ cat file2.csv
"1470009615","62353","1","y","52669","74568","php"
"1470009617","31173","1","y","54725","31173","php"
"1470009617","16293","1","n","58892","75842","php"
"1470009636","50795","1","y","47004","50795","php"
```

**Output**

```
$ awk -F, 'FNR==NR{gsub(/"/,"",$6);A[$6]++;next}{print $1,A[$1]+0}' file2.csv file1.dat
74568 1
75842 1
76822 0
77458 0
```

Comment: `++` for using `,` de-limiter, came up with the exact same logic!

Comment: Very good answer ++

Comment: Here if i need to change columns, like to search on columns 5 instead, i would change both $6 to $5? That is:
    awk -F, 'FNR==NR{gsub(/"/,"",$5);A[$5]++;next}{print $1,A[$1]+0}' file2.csv file1.dat

Comment: @MatheusCalvelli: Yes, but with given data it looks like you will get all zero

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know, it just an example, i have different files to search on.

Answer (score 0):

This `awk`solves the problem:

```
awk -F\" 'NR==FNR{a[$12]++;next}{print $1,$1 in a ? a[$1] : 0}' file2.csv file1.dat
```

**Explanation**

`NR==FNR{a[$12]++;next}`: When the **current** *Record Number* equals to the  *File Record Number* stores the key in `a` array, then `next` is used to avoid further processing for `file2.csv`

`{print $1, $1 in a ? a[$1] : 0}`: Just for `file1.dat` prints the first field, then the second value will be the number of appearances in `a` array or `0` if no one found. The [ternary](https://klashxx.github.io/ternary-operator) operator is used.